# Grails run-app doesn't

Tags: grails, run-app

I'm resurrecting a Grails project that was put on hold for a few years and I'm no longer able to use run-app. The project dates back to 1.3.7 and so does most of the infrastructure. The thing is, I spent a month or so bringing this back to life and everything has been working fine, in fact it's been in production for a few weeks already. Somehow I've managed to mess up the grails install and I can't figure out how or what is wrong. I made a small patch to the app (git agrees, only 2 files have changed), but when I start it via run-app, the embedded tomcat instance doesn't respond. Undoing my changes has no effect. The code all works fine, I can build the app and deploy to production, but I need run-app to work so that I can continue to develop (and eventually upgrade to a current version). The grails startup seems fine: all the usual messages are displayed (Welcome, License, Resolving Dependencies, Configuring Spring Security etc.), but once the app appears to have started (the localhost link is traced) browser requests merely time out.

I enabled sql logging and forced the Searchable plugin to rebuild its index on startup in dev mode and I can see the sql fly by, so I know that Hibernate can reach the db. I also know that the IDE isn't the issue, because I have the same problem running from the command line (the app appears to start normally, but browser requests are ignored). There is no exception or any other hints in the logs. Neither a clean, nor deleting .grails has had any effect, so it seems to be the grails install itself. I downloaded the old version of grails again and did a binary diff on the expanded dir structure, but Beyond Compare thinks the 2 installs are identical. Now I'm scratching my head about what to do next. Any ideas on why run-app might malfunction this way? Thanks

Edit: nothing in the logs of note (yes one of my domain classes is mapped to a view - it's never been a problem except for the warning) Pointing a browser to `http://localhost:8080/cgc` just times out, nothing appended to the logs.

```
spetroff@ubuntu:~/projects/cgc_srs$ grails run-app --verbose --stacktrace
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /usr/local/grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: /home/spetroff/projects/cgc_srs 
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 45152ms.
Running script /usr/local/grails-1.3.7/scripts/RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
[groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to /home/spetroff/projects/cgc_srs/target/classes
[delete] Deleting directory /home/spetroff/.grails/1.3.7/projects/cgc_srs/tomcat
Running Grails application..

Configuring Spring Security ...
Configuring Spring Security LDAP ...
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
2015-01-13 09:32:13,479 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table cgcv_sibling add constraint FKE1DE3C56430CD5A1 foreign key (person_id) references myt_person
2015-01-13 09:32:13,481 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Cannot alter 'cgcv_sibling' because it is not a table.
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/cgc
```

Comment: Hi Shane. It might be worthwhile including the output from a `grails run-app` execution in your question. There might be something hidden in there that you haven't spotted?

Comment: Try to run grails run-app --verbose --stacktrace and have a look at what is showing up

Comment: Not worth any further work. It's obviously environmental, so I just spun up another VM and reinstalled. Run-app works fine there